# How To Input Multiple Events into ImageButton?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

so i have this code and it works just fine to slide up and down a button, but i want to make it to work on multiple button by doing single click on imagebutton:

### Beranda.java

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_beranda);
    tombolSejarah = findViewById(R.id.tombolsejarah);
}


public void slideUpDown(final View view) {
     if (!isPanelShown()) {
         // Show the panel
         Animation bottomUp = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,
                 R.anim.buttom_up);
         tombolSejarah.startAnimation(bottomUp);
         tombolSejarah.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
     }else {
         // Sembunyikan
         Animation bottomDown = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,
                 R.anim.buttom_down);
         tombolSejarah.startAnimation(bottomDown);
         tombolSejarah.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}


private boolean isPanelShown() {
        return tombolSejarah.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE;
}
```

My imagebuttons : tombolsejarah, tombolkawasan, tombolsuku, tombolkebudayaan, tombolbahasa.

The question is how to make that happen?

Comment: could you please ellaborate your problem

Answer (score 0):

Try this. If this is not you want, I might need you to clarify your problem.

Implement `OnClickListener` to your activity

```
public class MyActivity extends AppCompact implements OnClickListener{}
```

In your `onCreate` find those button and set `onClickListener()`

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_beranda);
    tombolSejarah = findViewById(R.id.tombolsejarah);
    tombolSejarah.setOnClickListener(this);
    tombolkawasan = findViewById(R.id.tombolkawasan);
    tombolkawasan.setOnClickListener(this);
    tombolsuku = findViewById(R.id.tombolsuku );
    tombolsuku.setOnClickListener(this);
  .....
}
```

override `onClick()`

```
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        slideUpDown(v);
    }
```

for your slideUpDown(`view`)

```
public void slideUpDown(final View view) {//* <<<<watch at this view
    // the point here is, DO show animation on this view
    //not on tombolSejarah button.

 if (!isPanelShown()) {
     // Show the panel
     Animation bottomUp = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,
             R.anim.buttom_up);
     view.startAnimation(bottomUp);
     view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
 }else {
     // Sembunyikan
     Animation bottomDown = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,
             R.anim.buttom_down);
     view.startAnimation(bottomDown);
     view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
}
```

Comment: you should use your button as an input : private `boolean` isPanelShown(`View view`) { return `view`.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE; } or just `if (button.getVisibility()==View.VISIBLE)` without calling the function.

Comment: that's definitely what i want, but it doesn't work on my project.

and how about this code, what should i change in this one?



`private int isPanelShown() {
        return tombolSejarah.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE;
     }`

and can you give me more example on `public void slideUpDown`?

Answer (score 0):

This might be what you are looking for:

```
    public void slideUpDown(final View view) {
        if (!isPanelShown()) {

            Animation bottomUp = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,
                R.anim.buttom_up);
            view.startAnimation(bottomUp);
            view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {

            Animation bottomDown = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,
                R.anim.buttom_down);
            view.startAnimation(bottomDown);
            view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }
```

Pass the button on which you want to slide into this function.

Hope it helps.

Comment: i want to add tombolSuku, tombolBahasa, and more to do slide up and down just like tombolSejarah, and your answer doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

An option is to put your buttons in a single parent layout(`RelativeLayout` or `LinearLayout`) that you animate to slide the buttons up or down (This is if the buttons are to behave the same way on `imageButton` click).
You can name the parent view maybe `animator` and perform the operation you have in your code on that `view`.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_beranda);
    tombolSejarah = findViewById(R.id.tombolsejarah);

    //the parent view to handle animations when button is clicked
    animator = findViewById(R.id.animator);

    //Listening for click events
    animator.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            slideUpDown(v)
        }
    }
}


public void slideUpDown(final View view) {
    if (!isPanelShown()) {
        // Show the panel
        Animation bottomUp = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,
             R.anim.buttom_up);
        //tombolSejarah.startAnimation(bottomUp);
        //tombolSejarah.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        //animating view
        animator.startAnimation(bottomUp);
        animator.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }else {
        // Sembunyikan
        Animation bottomDown = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,
             R.anim.buttom_down);
        //tombolSejarah.startAnimation(bottomDown);
        //tombolSejarah.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        //animating view
        animator.startAnimation(bottomUp);
        animator.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
   }
}


private boolean isPanelShown() {
    return tombolSejarah.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE;
}
```

Comment: But how to insert tombolSejarah, tombolSuku, tombolKebudayaan, ... into "animator"?

Comment: you can add it just the way you create a normal layout with multiple views, either making `animator` a `RelativeLayout` or `LinearLayout` and put all the buttons (tombolSejarah, tombolSuku, tombolKebudayaan, etc) inside it. I did not add a layout file of such because I don't know what you have setup already on that side

Comment: @Nialixus was this response helpful to you or still need more help to solve this issue